# Rebus 7 IErrorHandler implementation not compatible with Rebus 8

Tags: rebus

I have this Rebus 7 `IErrorHandler` implementation to report failed messages on Slack:

```
public class ReportFailedMessageErrorHandler(
        IErrorHandler errorHandler,
        ISerializer serializer,
        SlackNotificationSender slackNotificationSender,
        IOptions<RuntimeOptions> runtimeOptions,
        LinkGenerator linkGenerator
    )
    : IErrorHandler
{
    public async Task HandlePoisonMessage(
        TransportMessage transportMessage, 
        ITransactionContext transactionContext,
        Exception exception
    )
    {
        await errorHandler.HandlePoisonMessage(transportMessage, transactionContext, exception);

        var rebusMessage = await serializer.Deserialize(transportMessage);
        
        var message = rebusMessage.Body as BaseMessage;
        Guard.Hope(message != null, nameof(message) + " is null");

        var shouldNotifyOnFail = message.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<NotifyOnFailAttribute>() != null;
        if (shouldNotifyOnFail && exception.InnerException is not IgnoreNotificationException)
        {
            var jobGuid = message switch
            {
                Command command => command.Guid,
                Event => Guid.Parse(rebusMessage.Headers[Headers.MessageId]),
                _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"Unsupported BaseMessage type {message.GetType().FullName}")
            };
            var failedMessageTypeName = message.GetType().Name;
            await slackNotificationSender.SendNotification(
                $"{failedMessageTypeName} failed",
                $"{_GetSlackJobLink(jobGuid, failedMessageTypeName)} failed on {runtimeOptions.Value.Environment}" +
                $"{(exception.InnerException is UserException ? $": {exception.InnerException.Message}" : ".")}",
                SlackNotificationSenderIconEmojiConstants.Warning,
                exception.InnerException is UserException
                    ? SlackNotificationSenderChannel.ContentChannel
                    : SlackNotificationSenderChannel.DevelopmentChannel
            );
        }
    }

    private string _GetSlackJobLink(Guid jobGuid, string messageTypeName)
    {
        return $"<{runtimeOptions.Value.Url.TrimEnd('/')}{_GetJobUrl(jobGuid)}|{messageTypeName}>";
    }

    private string _GetJobUrl(Guid jobGuid)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It uses `Exception.InnerException` to detect the exception thrown in the message handler, and behave differently based on the exception type.

In Rebus 8, `Exception` has been changed to `ExceptionInfo` without access to `InnerException`. I refactored the code to this:

```
    public async Task HandlePoisonMessage(
        TransportMessage transportMessage, 
        ITransactionContext transactionContext,
        ExceptionInfo exception
    )
    {
        await errorHandler.HandlePoisonMessage(transportMessage, transactionContext, exception);

        var rebusMessage = await serializer.Deserialize(transportMessage);
        
        var message = rebusMessage.Body as BaseMessage;
        Guard.Hope(message != null, nameof(message) + " is null");

        var shouldNotifyOnFail = message.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<NotifyOnFailAttribute>() != null;
        if (shouldNotifyOnFail && !exception.Details.Contains(nameof(IgnoreNotificationException)))
        {
            var jobGuid = message switch
            {
                Command command => command.Guid,
                Event => Guid.Parse(rebusMessage.Headers[Headers.MessageId]),
                _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"Unsupported BaseMessage type {message.GetType().FullName}")
            };
            var failedMessageTypeName = message.GetType().Name;
            await slackNotificationSender.SendNotification(
                $"{failedMessageTypeName} failed",
                $"{_GetSlackJobLink(jobGuid, failedMessageTypeName)} failed on {runtimeOptions.Value.Environment}" +
                $"{(exception.Details.Contains(nameof(UserException)) ? $": {exception.Message}" : ".")}",
                SlackNotificationSenderIconEmojiConstants.Warning,
                exception.Details.Contains(nameof(UserException))
                    ? SlackNotificationSenderChannel.ContentChannel
                    : SlackNotificationSenderChannel.DevelopmentChannel
            );
        }
    }
```

Not ideal in my opinion that the `InnerException` disappeared, and it's now doing a stringology (`exception.Details.Contains(nameof(UserException))`). Is there a better way in Rebus how to implement failed message reporting, and get access to the thrown inner exception message?

Comment: Check out this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/1122 and maybe also this page on the wiki: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling#exception-information

Comment: Created an issue from this: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/1154